# R - How can I add columns to a data frame / data.table based on values of a vector that contains a sequence of dates

Tags: r, data.table

I have a vector of dates

```
 start_date    <- as.Date("1990-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
 end_date      <- as.Date("2021-01-31", "%Y-%m-%d")

 new_cols      <- seq(from = start_date, 
                    to = end_date,
                    by = "month")
 new_cols      <- as.yearmon(new_col, frac = 1)
 new_col_names <- as.character(new_cols)
```

I have two other vectors one character vector that can be recycled when creating the data.frame and one integer vector.

```
ID.vec <- c(1:100)
type.vec <- c("A", "B", "C")

data.frame( rep(ID.vec, each = 3), type.vec, ?? )
```

Those date columns could be empty for all I care, as I am using a for loop to populate the table.

How can I add all dates defined in the sequence as columns to the data.frame/data.table, so that...

```
ID     TYPE    2000-03-31  2000-04-30  2000-05-31  2000-06-30 etc
1      A       sth         sth         sth         sth
1      B       sth         sth         sth         sth
1      C       sth         sth         sth         sth
2      A       sth         sth         sth         sth
2      B       sth         sth         sth         sth
2      C       sth         sth         sth         sth
3      A       sth         sth         sth         sth
3      B       sth         sth         sth         sth
3      C       sth         sth         sth         sth
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the columns to add as folows

```
df <- data.frame(rep(ID.vec, each = 3), type.vec)

someInitialValue <- 0
toAdd <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(rep(someInitialValue,NROW(df)*length(new_col_names)), 
                                    ncol = length(new_col_names), 
                                    nrow = NROW(df))), 
                  new_col_names)
```

and then bind them to your `data.frame` via

```
newdf <- cbind(df,toAdd)
```

Comment: Newer would have thought of that logical workaround myself! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this with `expand.grid`

```
out <- expand.grid(ID.vec, type.vec)
out[new_cols] <- NA
```